# Kivy: Mouse cursor not showing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I'm running kivy on a Raspberry Pi. I accepted that apparently you can't get around the fullscreen, but I can't get the cursor to show either. I tried by adding

```
touchring = show_cursor=true
```

to the [modules]-section of config.ini (in my home directory and the root directory), but it's not working. In the [graphics]-section

```
show_cursor = 1
```

is set as well, but nothing changes. Somebody know another solution?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the following line to the [modules]-section:

```
cursor = 1
```

I had the exact same problem as you did and it was terrible, but this one single line solved the issue.